# Como obter a quantidade de números repetidos em um vetor?

Tags: java

Preciso finalizar esse projeto, falta a impressão com a quantidade de números repetidos e quais números se repetem. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Entre com o valor N posições?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] vect = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Entre com o " + (i + 1) + "º. número = ");
            vect[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int qtdPares = 0;
        int qtdImpares = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {

            if (vect[i] % 2 == 0) {
                qtdPares++;
            } else {
                qtdImpares++;
            }
        }
       
        System.out.println("Pares = " + qtdPares);
        System.out.println("Impares = " + qtdImpares);

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Crie uma lista nova, percorra sua lista anterior e adicione cada valor a esta nova lista caso o valor já não esteja incluso.

Para verificar quantas vezes o valor aparece dentro da lista dê uma olhada [nesta documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).